# Select DISTINCT on JSONB column POSTGRES

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

I am trying to run a select distinct count query query on a JSONB column which stores a JSON payload and am having no end of trouble getting it right.

I have managed to retrieve the count of the array EmployeeData from the below payload but within that there is a Summary Object and in that a element called FileNumber. The JSONB is stored in a column called event

```
"EmployeeData": [
 {
  "Summary": {
   "FileNumber": "123456789",
   "FamilyName": "test",
   "FirstName": "test",
   "OtherName": "",
   "Pay": 7942.41,
   "Amount": 26311.00,
   "Other": 3000.00
  },
]
```

I can run this query successfully

`select DISTINCT event -> 'EmployeeData' as Data from mobile.payrun`

However if i try
 `select DISTINCT event -> 'EmployeeData' --> 'FileNumber' as Data from event_table`
It does not work

Can someone please let me know what the query should be to get DISTINCT count on the FileNumber element

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: 'EmployeeData' --> 'FileNumber' :: You have a key "Summary" in between, so this referencing might be wrong.

Comment: What if you have multiple elements in your `EmployeeData` array? Do you want to get all of them? Or just the first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `EmployeeData` is an array, you need to deal with potentially many elements in that array. In order to get them all (across all rows) you need to unnest the array:

```
select distinct d.element ->> 'FileNumber'
from event_table t
  cross join jsonb_array_elements(t.even -> 'EmployeeData') as d(element);
```

If you need the count use `count(distinct d.element ->> 'FileNumber')`

Comment: Thanks I will give it a try :)